# Trouble dereferencing pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am a bit of a sports better, and I am finding myself manually computing the decimal odds from the moneyline odds commonly found on many sportsbooks. I am trying to write a program that will at least remove the burden of calculating this over and over again.

My program is one that will take the inputs "team-one moneyline-teamone team-two moneyline-teamtwo" and output the team name with the decimal odds for a back and lay bet as below:

Input: Rams +230 Bucs -280

I have tried messing around with all of the permutations of dereferencing but can't seem to stop it from giving a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calcML(int a, float *b, float *c);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int oneML, twoML;
        float oneDF, oneDA, twoDF, twoDA;

        oneML = atoi(argv[2]);
        twoML = atoi(argv[4]);

        printf("Team one is %s with a ML of %i.\nTeam two is %s with a moneyline of %i.\n", argv[1], oneML, argv[3], twoML);

        calcML(oneML, &oneDF, &oneDA);
        calcML(twoML, &twoDF, &twoDA);

        printf("%s %f %f\n", argv[1], oneDF, twoDA);
        printf("%s %f %f\n", argv[3], twoDF, oneDA);
}

void calcML (int a, float *b, float *c)
{
        if (a < 0){
          int tmp = -a;
          *b = 1 + tmp/100;
          *c = 100/tmp;
        }
        else {
          *b = 1 + a/100;
          *c = 100/a;
        }
}
```

As above, I would expect the output to be:

```
Team one is Rams with a ML of +230.
Team two is Bucs with a ML of -280.
Rams  3.30 3.80
Bucs  1.36 1.43
```

Right now the output is:

```
Team one is Rams with a ML of +230.
Team two is Bucs with a ML of -280.
Segmentation fault
```

Like I said, I know it is a pointer arithmetic issue, but I have tried a million different permutations and can't figure it out. Thank you to any kind soul that doesn't mind pointing out my dumb mistake!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I suggest your very next step should be adding the first line in `main()` as `if(argc < 5) { /* handle error  */ }`

Comment: Not realted to the SEGFAULT, but you are discarding the fractional part when you assign to `b` and `c`.

Comment: I ran your code and did not get a seg fault.  I got this output: `Team one is Rams with a ML of 230.
Team two is Bucs with a moneyline of -280.
Rams 3.000000 0.000000
Bucs 3.000000 0.000000` with no seg fault.  Perhaps you changed your code and then forgot to compile before running it again?  The biggest clue is your output shows `ML` on the second line of output while the code given in the question outputs `moneyline` instead.

Comment: Aside: `tmp/100` performs integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the segfault, but as someone else has mentioned you appear to be accidentally truncating any floating point values. In `calcML`, when you execute `1 + tmp/100;` the compiler is "helping you" by coercing `tmp` to an integer. This was using `clang 10.0.1` on a MacBook. I would imagine that changing `1` to `1.0` and `100` to `100.0` will help clarify some of the math. Your pointers at least all look correct from what I can tell.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I think I posted this version without knowing that I had fixed it haha. I thought that it was wrong because it was giving me random numbers but it was really just because of the floating number error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the completed code after fixing the float and some of the arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calcML(int a, float *b, float *c);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int oneML, twoML;
        float oneDF, oneDA, twoDF, twoDA;

        oneML = atoi(argv[2]);
        twoML = atoi(argv[4]);

        printf("Team one is %s with a moneyline of %i.\nTeam two is %s with a moneyline of %i.\n", argv[1], oneML, argv[3], twoML);

        calcML(oneML, &oneDF, &twoDA);
        calcML(twoML, &twoDF, &oneDA);

        printf("%s %f %f\n", argv[1], oneDF, oneDA);
        printf("%s %f %f\n", argv[3], twoDF, twoDA);
}

void calcML (int a, float *b, float *c)
{
        if (a < 100){
          float tmp = -a;
          *b = 1.0 + 100.0/tmp;
          *c = tmp/100.0 + 1;
        }
        else {
          *b = 1.0 + a/100.0;
          *c = 100.0/a + 1;
        }
}
```